# How to execute a stored procedure from string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

So, I'm trying to execute a stored procedure from a string to get a wide range of data but I get a

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

How do I probably execute my stored procedure

```
public class CarBLL
{

    public static string GetCar(string carnumberxx, string authTicketxx)
    {
        using (var context = new SindalDBEntities())
        {
            var doerTicket = "0x0100000067294c938207c9e5e0cb6b98ddc4edd9464bc14e68b59cbc73c9dc559c5d43ad9b3705d1720a52542e0220b7df11b2e4bd913d873b1aa18c";
            var stamdata = "G0057";
            String sql =
            "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +
            "EXEC [file].[usp_getCar] " +
            "@p_CarNumber= '" + stamdata + "', " +
            "@p_DoerTicket= '" + doerTicket + "' ";
            List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("CarNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, stamdata));
            sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("DoerTicket", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, doerTicket));
            return context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sql).FirstOrDefault<string>();
      } 
    }
}
}
```

If I try to exclude one of my parameters from the SP as

```
public static usp_getCar_Result GetCar(string carnumber, string authTicket)
   {
 using (var context = new SindalDBEntities())
         {
          int? id = null;
         // ObjectParameter Id = new ObjectParameter("p_ID", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        // ObjectResult result = new ObjectResult("usp_getCar_Result", typeof(string));
        return context.usp_getCar(id, carnumber, authTicket).FirstOrDefault(); 
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

I gets a

> Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SindalDbModel.usp_getCar_Result'. A member of the type, 'ID1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: Your tags are all wrong.

Comment: well is an web api maded in entitty and C#?

Comment: Honestly if you inly search entity-framework stored procedure you would get the answer you want

Comment: trust me i had been searching for a solution for the past 2 days now and none of thoose i had found worked so thats why i had created this

Answer (score 1):

It's better to import your `usp_getCar` stored procedure to your DbContext. See this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx).

In this case you will have a strongly typed method in your `SindalDBEntities`. So you will be able to just execute it:

```
return context.GetCar(stamdata, doerTicket).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i had tryed that but i couldn't get it to work out with null 1 of the parameters(p_ID) that i do not use for anything in this function so thats why i tryed to use string so i could exclude it